# Thread safety guarantees for Objective-C runtime functions?

Tags: objective-c

What are the guarantees about thread safety for Objective-C runtime functions? Are there any? I am talking about the functions declared in runtime.h (e.g. class_lookupMethod, objc_setAssociatedObject).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of it is thread safe -- swizzling, and the like -- but some of it isn't.  looking up a method should be.   Associated objects may not be.  If they aren't explicitly documented as such, then they should be treated as not being thread safe.

Have a look at the source for the runtime.  The comments therein may be illuminating.  And please file a bug asking for clarification in the docs, if not already very clear.

Comment: Thanks, that is illuminating. Is it reasonable to expect if an implementation goes out of its way at the moment to make something thread safe, that it won't change in the near future? I took a look at http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/objc-references.mm which utilizes a spin lock for getting/setting associative references. I'll file a bug report asking for more documentation too.

Comment: It would be reasonable to assume that any implementation documented as thread-safe in a (released) API or runtime will remain thread-safe--though anything's possible of course, so it's always a good idea to read release notes of future versions.

Comment: Yes -- it is unlikely that something that is currently intentionally thread safe will regress to thread unsafe in the future, both because that'd be a step backwards and it would incur binary compatibility wrath.   Obviously, proper documentation makes the contract all that much stronger.